# Handle empty fields - handlebarjs

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, release-notes

I'm using [XplatGenerateReleaseNotes](https://github.com/rfennell/AzurePipelines/tree/main/Extensions/XplatGenerateReleaseNotes) plugin for my release notes.

I want to handle my #if that recognizes when a custom field is empty. I found in the plugin source code that there is a helper called "isEmpty", but I can't get it to work.

Here is my template:

```
{{#return_parents_only this.workItems this.relatedWorkItems}}
{{#if (or (contains (lookup this.fields 'System.WorkItemType') 'User Story') (contains (lookup this.fields 'System.WorkItemType') 'Feature'))}}
{{#if (isEmpty (lookup this.fields 'Custom.ReleaseNotes'))}}
emtpy
{{else}}
{{#with fields}}
* **{{{get 'System.Title' this}}}:** {{{sanitize (get 'Custom.ReleaseNotes' this)}}}
{{/with}}
{{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{/return_parents_only}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the `isEmpty` helper come from?

Comment: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#isempty 

I was thinking about using the lengthEqual to check if the length of the given field is 0.

Comment: Yes, the `isEmpty` documentation says it takes a collection. Assuming your target value is a string, I think the [equalsLength helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#equalslength) would be a good choice.